# POSTGRES - add whitespace

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called item and I would like to add whitespace at the START of each row in the item column.

I would also like to remove the 3 and insert the result into a new column called item_n.

```
item                 item_n
-------------------|-----------
to go 3            |
1 2 3              |
cat dog 3          |
blah blah 3
```

RESULT:

```
item          |  item_n
------------------------------
to go 3       | to go
1 2 3         | 1 2
cat dog 3     | cat dog
blah blah 3   | blah blah
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: Your title and your sample data don't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will give you the perfect answer

```
Select concat(' ', replace(item,' 3',' ')) from table name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `left()` with a negative second argument:

```
select left(item, -2) as item_n
```

If you know that the " 3" only appears at the end of the string, you can do:

```
select replace(item, ' 3', '')
```

Or, if the " 3" might not be in the string, then `case` is one solution:

```
select (case when item like '% 3' then left(item, -2) else item
        end) as item_n
```

You can prepend white space by using string concatenation:

```
select ' ' || left(item, -2) as item_n
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I create the whitespace at the start of all rows in item_n?

Comment: @Paul . . . You can concatenate spaces, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I know it's hard to see from my example but in the item_n column in the results there is whitespace at the front

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nice answer with different solutions . Thank you

Comment: Thanks for you help!